# How to make reasonable assumptions about stack works

Tags: java, android, opencv, embedded, embedded-linux

For example, given an openCV application, 1920*1080 HD at rate 60 fps involves a combination of filtering, subsampling and so on.(it's ok if you not familiar with this...)

Generally speaking, how can I find key memory storage for an application? I have no clue about how to find out based on what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make reasonable assumptions about stack works

You don't need to make assumptions.  It is documented in the JVM specification (at the abstract level), and the mapping of the abstract to the concrete is common sense.

> Generally speaking, how can I find key memory storage for an application?

Assuming that you are asking about stack space usage:

- The (theoretical) way to predict stack usage is to analyse the code to figure out all of the possible call paths.  Then for each method call on each call path, calculate the individual stack frame usage (sum the space for the local variables + the parameters + the call overhead), and sum for all calls.  The max stack usage is the maximum of the call path sums.
- The practical way is to run the application and see how much stack memory it actually needs; i.e. set specific stack sizes and see if the application crashes with a `StackOverflowError`.

For heap memory, predicting the usage is even more difficult, unless your application's memory usage patterns are simple and stable.  Even measuring it is tricky.

---

And of course, these things are likely to be highly application dependent, platform dependent, and dependent on the "inputs" to your application.

My recommendation: don't even try.  It is too hard to get numbers that are going to be reliable enough to be useful.

Comment: Thanks! Is how many data (like the sum of stream) need to be buffered can consider roughly the memory required for the application?

Comment: Possibly yes, probably no.  It depends on how the respective libraries are implemented